# An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString. An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

[image: I am using Oledb connection for database connectivity but i am getting error be sure i am not using SQL server i am using Microsoft access 2013]

I am using Oledb connection for database connectivity but i am getting error be sure i am not using SQL server i am using Microsoft access 2013

Comment: What is your connection string _exactly_?

Comment: Look at your app.config file, search for a line with ConnectionString matching the key you have used in the program to retrieve the connection settings and show that line to us. It is probably wrong

Comment: <add name="MYDBConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=EmployeeDatabase; Integrated Security=SSPI;" />

Comment: That string is invalid for MS-Access, take a look here [www.connectionstrings.com/access](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)

Comment: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; when i put this code in app.config file this also give an error  the Provider Name is not allowed

Comment: The oledb connection with access database is possible only for 32bit application, check if your project is running x86 (Look at project properties). If you don't have oledb12 you may try with "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oledb connection string to use with Access should be like:

```
<add name="MYDBConnectionString" 
connectionString= "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<path>\yourAccessFile.accdb" />
```

Make sure you have [access database engine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) registered on your machine. Also install the correct 32 bit or 64 bit according to you system architecture.